# Let $C \subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a compact set. Let $I$ be the set or the isolated points of $C$, prove that $I$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I'm thinking of using the fact that $C$ is compact to find a contradiction, because for any open covering of $C$ there should be a finite subcover. 
Know, if $C$ has an infinite number of isolated points you will need to use an infinite number of open balls (centered at every isolated point) to get a finite subcover. That is absurd.
Is my proof going in the right direction?

Comment: Am I missing something? Connected compact subsets (and more) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ need not have any isolated points..

Comment: After the edit It's more unclear what you are asking now..... What do you mean by at least a finite number of isolated points? Is $0$ a finite number?

Comment: @C.I.J. This is false, see the answer as an example

Comment: Oh, I don't know why I wrote that..let me delete my comment

Comment: Yeah, the original problem was to prove that if $C$ is compact, then it must have a finite number of isolated points, but a good guy shown a counterexample below here. So I thought that there's something unclear about the problem, tried to rewrote it, failed and now I'm making another edit.

Comment: There is a simple counterexample: the interval $[0,1]^n,$ it is compact but it has no isolated points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, this is false. Take $$ C = \prod_{i=1}^{n} [0,1]_i \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$$ Then, $C$ is a perfect set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so every point of $C$ is a limit point. Ergo, there does not exist a point such that it can be surrounded by a neighborhood not containing another point of $C$. In general, any compact connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ will not have an isolated point. There are many more examples, however.

Comment: Thank you all guys, you rock.

Comment: @user264983 Not a problem. Happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb{R}$, let $X = \{0\} \bigcup \{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots \}$. Then $X$ is compact and has infinitely many isolated points.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Let me rewrite the problem.